# Need help integrating DataTables in my website

Tags: datatables

Alright, I've downloaded the necessary files from DataTables.net, but I'm struggling with actually getting it into my site. How exactly do I reference it? Their website says

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example').dataTable();
});
```

Takes care of the initialization, but obviously the code needs to be referenced (like how I reference javascript for example):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="view/javascript/application.js" ></script>
```

Can somebody just give me some pointers with this? I understand it's a simple question but I'm a little lost and going through their website isn't giving me much help with it as it mostly seems to be focused on actually using the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how I bind [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js) dataTables into web projects:

1) First jQuery needs to be referenced, since DataTables is a jQuery plug-in. Without jQuery DataTables won't work.

```
<!--jQuery -->
<script src="Project/Scripts/jQuery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

2) You reference the DataTables plugin:

```
    <!--Data Tables -->
    <script src="Project/Scripts/DataTables/jQuery_DataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

3) Decide in what manner you wan to use DataTables. [You have 4 options](http://datatables.net/usage/): DOM, JavaScript array, JSON object, ServerSide Processing.
DOM is the simplest if you just want to test if your DataTables is working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ $('#table_id').dataTable(); });
</script>
<table id="table_id">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>etc</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        <td>etc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        <td>etc</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Considerations:

1. Make sure your FilePaths and FileNames are correct.
2. Make sure your [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js) is new enough for your version of [DataTables](http://datatables.net/download/)
3. Using DataTables with server-side processing is a bit more difficult than the other 3 options.